# XMPPError: not-acceptable - modify when trying to kick user from room

Tags: java, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

Java Smack lib has method:

```
public void kickParticipant(String nickname, String reason)
```

But there is `nickname` as argument. I have user JID's... So, I tried to get nickname for users:

```
mChats.get(room).getMembers().forEach(user -> LOG.debug(user.getNick() + ", " + user.getJid()));
```

And I see:

```
null, 4_1@localhost 
null, 113_1@localhost
```

I tried just pass login of user (e.g. '113_1') and got error:

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: not-acceptable - modify
```

As mentioned in [spec](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0086.html#sect-idp653152) it means `<bad-request/>`.

I tried pass `nickname` in different formats: `nickname`, `roomname@domen/nickname`, `nickname@host`. And got same error.

However for C# I use Matrix library. And there is method:

```
KickUser(Jid room, string nickname);
```

And it works fine when I tried to pass here user login (e.g. `113_1`) as argument.

Am I right when passing user login as argument to kick method? If yes, how can I avoid this error?